# Is it possible to make cargo use rustc --explain E0495 option?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My code, compile with `cargo build`, gives:

> error: aborting due to previous error; 16 warnings emitted
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.

I want to know more about this error but I don't know how to compile alone with `rustc`. Can I force Cargo to use the `--explain E0495` option?

If not, can I make Cargo output the entire `rustc` calls it's using so I can simply copy and add `--explain E0495`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The `--explain` option is not to be used while compiling your code but it is used standalone to get a quick explanation of the error.

Comment: @rodrigo I thought it'd detail the explanation of the compilation error on my specific file, but now that you said that I realized it's just a manual